# Display multiple JSON records in NextJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

In the NextJS tutorial we are shown how to render a list of Batman show names from a map.
[Fetching Batman Shows](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows)

In that tutorial there is this fragment that gets the data from the map:

```
<ul>
  {props.shows.map(({show}) => (
    <li key={show.id}>
      <Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?id=${show.id}`}>
        <a>{show.name}</a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

But what if the JSON document is much simpler e.g.

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "text":"first doc",
 },
 {
  "id":2,
  "text":"second doc",
 }
]
```

How do you prepare the data set (got via the `getInitialProps` call) and access from the `props` data?

With this example data the goal would be to build a HTML list of values of `"text"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't overly obvious to me from the React documents [React Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). The map function is for any array that needs to be rendered.

Any top level element of a JSON record can be mapped.

```
  <ul>
  {props.mydata.map(({id, text}) => (
    <li key={id}>
      <Link as={`/p/${id}`} href={`/post?id=${id}`}>
        <a>{text}</a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```